# "C:/Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command - Setting up Lua with LOVE and Sublime text 2

Tags: lua, sublimetext2

I am trying to use the LOVE graphics library for Lua, and use Sublime text 2 to write in. The LOVE website says i can use this code:

```
{
    "selector": "source.lua",
    "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/LOVE/love.exe", "$file_path"],
    "shell": true
}
```

to create a build system that will allow me to run my scripts directly from inside Sumblime text. but when i use this build system with ctrl+B it says:

" 'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

it is stopping at the space in "Program Files". how do i stop it doing this?

Comment: c:/progra~1/love/love.exe

Comment: `"cmd": ["\"C:/Program Files/LOVE/love.exe\"", "$file_path"],`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space in the filename that is being wrongly used as a parameter delimiter.

Depending on your environment you can either double quote the executable name or use `dir /x` to get the short (8.3) filename for the path.

Answer (score -1):

You can just move `"LOVE"` directory in `C` Drive like

```
C:\LOVE
```

It will work.